# How do you remove the restrictors from Hansgrohe & Axor faucets?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I want to remove flow restrictors from hansgrohe & Axor faucets. After the thermostatic cartrige in the shower went bad, I started digging in and found a selector restrictor that prevented both showerheads from functioning at the same time. After this, I started thinking about the faucets, both the bathroom and kitchen faucets have weak flow. The faucets are relatively new and I don't believe clogging is an issue, there are 5 in the house and they all have the same weak, aerated flow. I've searched for a guide but have only seen the ones to remove restrictors in the shower heads (doing that after).

If someone could point to the specific parts that need to be removed to improve flow in this kitchen faucet, or if you have a guide, I would appreciate it. I was going to include the bathroom faucets, however this is my first time posting here and I'm not sure how to do multiple pictures with clarity, so I'll save that for another day if I can't figure it out after doing this kitchen faucet.
[image: exploded drawing]

Comment: Looks to me like spray head should unscrew.  Maybe parts 5,23, or the part directly at the 25 is the restrictor (although it's probably really an aerator)?

Comment: Do you have a tankless WH? Low flow shower heads and kitchen sink faucet and levatory faucets work welll together. If you remove the flow restrictor on a shower you could make it  difficult to operate two showers at the same time. Someone will be showering in a restricted shower head and have the waater suddenly go cold if one unrestricted hot delivery point is opened elsewhere. We have an old and relatively small gas fired tankless WH. If soemone is showering and I open the unrestricted hot at the utility sink in the garage or the unrestricted tub valve, the shower goes cold!

Comment: In our kitchen sink the flow restrictor is in the aerator assembly at the veny end. If you take it off to try this, make a note of orientation and order of parts (take pics) for resstoration.

Comment: Thanks @huesmann.  This is in a condo building and there's abundant hot water and pressure. I'll try to take off the end and see what happens. I'm not too worried about getting it back together or voiding the warranty jim stewart. What I'm getting from both of you guys is you think it's at the end of the nozzle, not in the faucet or on/off handle, correct?

Comment: @artfart54 every restrictor I've seen has been in the "head" area.

Comment: @Huesmann I figured it out. Take off the entire end of the faucet. looking inside from the top down, there was a yellow plastic piece. A 6mm socket fit inside perfectly. Press it down in and then pull it out. Good news is the regular stream of water is much faster. The bad news is the spray feature still sucks, no way to clean food off dishes. I'm going to see if I can't replace the aerator on the tip. The restrictor wasn't the weakest link of the faucet, it's the aerator at the end.